# How to print multiple text area with same name in fpdf? I used a loop

Tags: php, loops, fpdf

i used a loop based on user input of how many products are defective.

if the user inputs 3, there would be 3 text areas and so on.

my problem is that how do i print the list in fpdf? it has the same name and i dont know how to do it.

here is my code for the looping.

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{
        echo '<input type="text" name="prod" class="span3"><input type="number" name="qty" class="span3" min="1" max="99" style="width:60px;"><br>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$i` to make unique `name` fields.

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{
        echo '<input type="text" name="prod_$i" class="span3">
              <input type="number" name="qty_$i" class="span3" min="1" max="99" style="width:60px;"><br>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Okay, so how do i make it display all of the list? let's say im just going to echo it in another php page. how do i do it?

Comment: I didn't understand clearly,Are you want send data to another page like in a form submission.?

Comment: Yes, Like a form submission, i would submit all the values inside the text input, and how would i display them all?

Comment: give form `action="yourpage.php"` `method="post"` in submition all the form data sent to php page. In that page you can access data using the name field like `$_POST['prod_1'],$_POST['qty_1']` etc...

Comment: How do i display them all? not individually, because the loop always depends on how many the user inputs. so how would i display them all by not using it individually.

Comment: Use `ajax` in form submit get the form data using `serialize` function then send the formData to php page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63919/discussion-between-gowri-and-user3927531).